# how to integrate local active directory folders to google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an local active directory server and a few shared folders with permissions in that the created users from the active directory have an account that has those files saved in a google cloud storage, i would like to know if there is a way to use the files from google cloud so that the admin is able to manage the permissions and users from the active directory. If not, what other solutions can i use?

Thanks!

Comment: [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) might be relevant, althought I don't think it can work on Windows.